# Should the Code Contracts static checker be able to check arithmetic bound?

Tags: static-analysis, math, code-contracts

(Also [posted on the MSDN forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/codecontracts/thread/07b5f3f1-082f-48eb-bcfd-fcac9f373d3b) - but that doesn't get much traffic, as far as I can see.)

I've been trying to provide an example of `Assert` and `Assume`. Here's the code I've got:

```
public static int RollDice(Random rng)
{
    Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<int>() >= 2 &&
                     Contract.Result<int>() <= 12);

    if (rng == null)
    {
        rng = new Random();
    }
    Contract.Assert(rng != null);

    int firstRoll = rng.Next(1, 7);
    Contract.Assume(firstRoll >= 1 && firstRoll <= 6);

    int secondRoll = rng.Next(1, 7);
    Contract.Assume(secondRoll >= 1 && secondRoll <= 6);

    return firstRoll + secondRoll;
}
```

(The business about being able to pass in a null reference instead of an existing `Random` reference is purely pedagogical, of course.)

I had hoped that if the checker knew that `firstRoll` and `secondRoll` were each in the range `[1, 6]`, it would be able to work out that the sum was in the range `[2, 12]`.

Is this an unreasonable hope? I realise it's a tricky business, working out exactly what might happen... but I was hoping the checker would be smart enough :)

If this isn't supported now, does anyone here know if it's likely to be supported in the near-ish future?

EDIT: I've now found that there are very complicated options for arithmetic in the static checker. Using the "advanced" text box I can try them out from Visual Studio, but there's no decent explanation of what they do, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Jon, have you tried contacting the guys from DevLabs directly? You will find the team members listed at the bottom of this page: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/

Comment: And their e-mail address is codconfb _at_ microsoft _dot_ com (as mentioned on the same page). I would be interested to know the answer to your question.

Comment: I thought it would be a bit more polite to ask questions in the forum first... if I don't hear back on the forums or here, I'll ask by email too.

Comment: Just as a side issue: does this look like a reasonable example?

Comment: I agree Jon, although I feel that there is no user base (yet) for this rather new tool. And btw, your sample seems quite reasonable to me.

Comment: Glad the sample looks okay - have emailed the team now (with 4 questions). I think the user base needs to be kick-started a bit, which is something I'm hoping to do with the book.

Comment: As you include it in your book I am wondering whether Code Contracts will be part of .NET 4.0? It wasn't part of the CTP afaik and I couldn't find any other information except that it is only free with an academic license.

Comment: @divo: The core libraries are part of .NET 4.0 (in mscorlib) but the tools aren't (currently). They're a free download, but you only get the static checker if you've got Team System installed, I believe.

Comment: Jon, so the static checker will not be in regular VS 2010? If so, then we might as well not have contracts, as not everyone uses the team system.

Comment: @Joan: You're assuming that code contracts have no value without static checking. I disagree with that assumption.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've had an answer on the MSDN forum. It turns out I was very nearly there. Basically the static checker works better if you split out "and-ed" contracts. So, if we change the code to this:

```
public static int RollDice(Random rng)
{
    Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<int>() >= 2);
    Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<int>() <= 12);

    if (rng == null)
    {
        rng = new Random();
    }
    Contract.Assert(rng != null);

    int firstRoll = rng.Next(1, 7);
    Contract.Assume(firstRoll >= 1);
    Contract.Assume(firstRoll <= 6);
    int secondRoll = rng.Next(1, 7);
    Contract.Assume(secondRoll >= 1);
    Contract.Assume(secondRoll <= 6);

    return firstRoll + secondRoll;
}
```

That works without any problems. It also means the example is even more useful, as it highlights the very point that the checker *does* work better with separated out contracts.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the MS Contracts Checker tool, but range analysis is a standard static analysis technique; it is widely used in commercial static analysis tools to verify that subscript expressions are legal.

MS Research has a good track record at this kind of static analysis, and so I'd expect doing such range analysis to be a goal of the Contracts Checker, even if not presently checked.